# Показ Одной-Последней загруженной картинки из папки php

Tags: php

Нашел код, но он показывает все изображения из папки.Мне нужно чтобы из папки показывало только Одно последнее загруженное туда фото.Вот если что код:

```
    <?php
 function search_img($path){ 
      $html="";
    foreach (glob($path."*{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename){
        $file[filemtime($filename)] = $filename ;
    }   
    krsort($file);  
    reset($file);

    foreach ($file as $k => $v){

        $html .= '<img class="lp-g" src="'.$v.'" />';
    }   
      return $html;
}
 ?>
 <?php echo search_img("images/"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас уже все сделано и отсортировано. Осталось только получить первое значение массива:

```
$html .= '<img class="lp-g" src="' . array_shift($file) . '" />';
```